# SQL developer GUI function permission

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

After granting the user the ability to create functions by adding the

```
grant create procedure to user;
```

I've successfully created a function by code with no problems. However, when using the GUI in SQL Developer to create the function an error appears indicating that I have no permission to create a function. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Did you log out and log back in after applying the grant? Are you logged in with the same user account to which the grant was applied?

Comment: yes, I'm logged in to the same user I've granted I would publish a picture of the error also. But unfortunately I don't have enough reputation.And as I stated I can do it by code but in the GUI it doesn't work.